# Getting error when using following function for initialize

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I am using following function in js file for initialising other parameters

```
$(document).bind("ready", initialize);
```

This function will work well when we refresh a page or coming on that page for first time
But when we have an ajax call on that page since it will not have document "ready" so it will not bind and call that initialize function,
Any idea how we do it,
is there anything like

```
$(document).bind("ready,ajax", initialize);
```

Comment: huh ? $.ajax().done(callback) is as close as you're gonna get ..that, and this: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I tried this way and it worked

    $(document).ready(initialize);
But still thanks all for kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on({
    ready: initialize,
    ajaxComplete: initialize
});
```

Use `on` instead of `bind` which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply . I m trying this

Comment: I tried this way and it worked

    $(document).ready(initialize);
But still thanks all for kind help

Comment: Blind me ...ready is better, but in terms of code you posted it would have looked like this $(document).on("load", initialize); btw try taking the habit of using .on/off() not bind/unbind, they are deprecated

Comment: Right, changed to `on`.